# When integrating by parts, are you allowed to multiply the inside of the integral by 1?

Tags: calculus, integration

In my Calculus class, my prof showed us how to integrate $\int \ln(x)dx$ by using integration by parts. In my notes we were able to multiply by the $\ln(x)$ by $1$ to get $\int (1)\ln(x)dx$. Then, we would integrate by parts to get $x\ln(x)-\int x(1/x)dx$ and then the final answer was $x\ln(x) - x + C$.

My question is then, could you not multiply any integral by $1$ and just keep getting more x variables inside when you integrate it?

For example if I took that $\int (1)\ln(x)dx$ and multiplied it by $1$ again to get $\int (1)(1)\ln(x)dx$ and calculated the integral, would both the ones turn evaluate to x?

Comment: Try writing it out and see what you get

Comment: Rewrite the question to show explicitly what u and dv are in your conceptual example and you will probably see where the issue is.

Comment: You are not multiplying by 1, you are just using the fact that $f(x)=1\cdot f(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that when taking the integral, $1$ becomes $x$, but you are integrating one $1$. If you are integrating both $1$'s then $1\times1=1$ so you still get $x$. And if you choose another $1$, you still get the same result. Great thinking though!